# how to query a blob data

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like :

```
------------------------------
Test_Id           Test_data
(String)          (blob)
------------------------------
```

I want a query to retrieve all the Test_Id's for a matching Test_data.

To achieve something like : select * from test_table where Test_data = blobObject;

How can we do above ??

Comment: Can you elaborate more on `blobObject` that you are comparing

Answer (score 8):

First: there's no such thing as a string in MySQL. Only char/varchar/text.

Well you could cast it as char for comparison like this:

```
select * from test_table where Test_data = CAST( blobObject AS CHAR );
```

what's probably better is to convert your string to a binary string, but this might not give you the right comparison if you expect string comparison behaviour... well best you have a look at the char functions here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: How do you know the string's length for a language like C++?

Answer (score 3):

**You can use a hash function such as MD5**

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE MD5(blob_column) = 'a6a7c0ce5a93f77cf3be0980da5f7da3';
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has data types which can store binary data. Not only char/varchar/text, but also BINARY/VARBINARY/BLOB.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html

And it's usage is as simple as normal string type. But, escaping is required. and query length is must specified because binary data may contain NULL character in their contents.

Before MySQL 3.23 (I guess), There were only mysql_query(), mysql_escape_string(). Those function has no capability specifying query length. after BLOB has been introduced in MySQL, mysql_real_query() and mysql_real_escape_string() supported.

I found some examples for you. May this links help you!

http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/558973-c-client-load-binary-data-mysql